# Overiding AWT and storing graphics

Tags: java, awt, graphics2d

-Hi all! I'm making a Java applet that simulates wave interference, which I have almost finished (will license under GPL). However, I have two questions regarding the AWT paint cycle that I am having difficulty finding answers to.

1. I want to make an 'about' overlay that appears when I press a button. The way I want to do this is to draw over the entire applet window with my static message and legend objects. The problem is stopping the AWT components from drawing themselves in the foreground without using remove(). Is there a way I can stop AWT from drawing itself temporarily?
2. For my standing waves mode I want to have node and anti-node markers calculated and drawn to a secondary graphics every time the standing wave reaches a maximum amplitude (all of which I can do myself), but drawn to the primary graphics (and thus displayed) every paint cycle. Could someone explain the steps to do so? I imagine it would involve creating a second graphics object, drawing to it once, then drawing it to the primary graphics every cycle.

If you are able to answer either of my questions I would be very grateful!

Cheers, Jack Allison

Answer (score 0):

Responding to your first question:

You can't disable the `paint()`/`paintComponent()` method if you've inlcluded it in your code. If its there, it runs. However, you can create a flag so that only if the flag is true, the stuff gets drawn. Let me show you what I mean:

```
boolean flag;

...

public void paintComponent(Graphics comp) {
    if (flag) {
        Graphics2D comp2D = (Graphics2D) comp;
        //drawing statements
    }
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    flag = true;
    repaint();
}
```